# any software and ubuntu can't conect to internet (i leave my output, but in portuguese...)

Tags: software-center, update-manager, connection, internet-connection

This is what happens when i do "sudo apt-get update"... :s and it is NOT the temporary error, as far as I understood...i tried everything...

```
Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-pt_PT
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-pt
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-pt_BR
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-pt_PT
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-pt
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-pt_BR
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-pt_PT
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-pt
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-pt_BR
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-pt_PT
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-pt
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-pt_BR
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)
W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_PT  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-pt  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-pt_BR  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

W: Falhou obter http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Algo estranho aconteceu ao resolver 'proxy.e-u:8080' (-5 - Não existe um endereço associado ao nome de servidor)

E: Alguns arquivos index falharam ao ser baixados. Eles foram ignorados, ou cópias antigas são usadas ao invés.
```

Comment: humm...i dont know... But when im in school everything works.. In my home network doesnt. I erased the home networks (cable and wireless), and i'll see what happens when i arrive home.

Comment: here is a screenshot of the update manager. The problem stills... http://c9.quickcachr.fotos.sapo.pt/i/ocd09ec30/11543683_zpiqC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a proxy problem. in System Definitions (i dunno if it is like this in english) you go to networks, and take off the proxy and then click on the button which is bellow. :)

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Execute: `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Why would this help?